# variable in xpath

Tags: xpath, xquery, exist-db

I'm writing xquery on [eXist](http://exist.sourceforge.net/).

Usually I use this way to select item in xml:

```
fn:doc($document_name)/root/a
```

But now I wants to get the xpath from a string variable:

```
let $xpath := request:get-parameter("xpath", "")
fn:doc($document_name)/$xpath
```

Of course it doesn't work.
The only way I found now is using `eval`:

```
util:eval(fn:concat("fn:doc($document_name)", $xpath)):)
```

but i don't want to use `eval` because it's slow and not safe.

I know there's something like:

```
fn:doc($document_name)/*[name()='node_name']
```

but I want to select item via the whole path but not only the name of node
and I also have tried to use `node-xpath()` but don't know how to use it just like `name()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to do what the eval() function does, so any solution is going to have the same problems as eval. The other approach you could consider is generating a query and then executing it, but it will have exactly the same problems. If you think it might be safer to restrict the string to a subset of XPath expressions (e.g. with no predicates, or no function calls) then you could try testing for those conditions using simple regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

despite Michael Kay being right, maybe the [functx:dynamic-path](http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/functx_dynamic-path.html)() is of some help.

It might be a good intermediate solution sitting between fn:eval and generating the query dynamically.

Hope this helps

Michael

Comment: I'm not sure whether it's a good idea or not, but at least eXist doesn't support this function now.

Comment: @owen_water You need to include the functx library. See: http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/functx-1.0-doc-2007-01.xq